# How to include markdown file (md) inside mdx file

Tags: markdown, mdxjs

plain.md

```
# plain markdown
```

some.mdx

```
# some mdx file

include './plain.md'
```

Result file

```
# some mdx file

# plain markdown
```

How to do something like this with [mdxjs](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh, that's actually right in [their docs](https://mdxjs.com/docs/using-mdx/#components). Was known as transclusion some time ago.

```
import License from './license.md'
import Contributing from './docs/contributing.mdx'

# Hello, world!

<License />

---

<Contributing />
```

Comment: Looks like this is the new link for that part of the docs: https://mdxjs.com/docs/using-mdx/#components

Comment: I feel like they made their docs worse in comparison than it was before, now there is no implicit mention of transclusion anymore, but the example remains the same

Comment: the note now says "// Assumes an integration is used to compile MDX -> JS." which explains why this isn't working for me i guess, but i'm not sure what i need to do (in storybook)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you should have the "transclusion" feature activated in your bundler (eg: webpack)

If you are using storybook, you can follow this steps:

1- On your *main.js* file, set `{ transcludeMarkdown: true }` on the *"@storybook/addon-docs"* addon.

```
// .storybook/main.js
module.exports = {
  addons: [
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-docs",
      options: { transcludeMarkdown: true },
    },
  ],
  // ...
};
```

2- Import the .md on your .mdx file and render it like a Component

```
//Example.stories.mdx
import MyMarkdown from './MyMarkdown.md'

...

<MyMarkdown />
```